# Classifier fit and predict on the same data gives different result

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am training a classifier using sklearn and I am doing something wrong. In the code below I put exactly the same values for training and predicting and the results are not the same. How does this happen?

```
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                     ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                     ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
])
text_clf = text_clf.fit(X, y)

predicted = text_clf.predict(X)

print set(np.asarray(y)) == set(predicted) #gives false
```

The data X is a list of unicode and y list of numbers (1 and 0).

Answer (score 4):

In general, no, the two will not be equal.  Unless you use a method that converges only on 100% training accuracy, you will get less than perfect fitting.

Forcing 100% accuracy in ML generally causes *over-fitting*, resulting in a model that is so specifically adapted to the training set, that it gives unacceptably poor performance on any later (e.g. real-world) input.

If you *require* 100% accuracy, then Machine Learning is altogether the wrong paradigm for your problem.  You need deterministic classification, not an adaptive heuristic.

Comment: I did it just for a try to see if it works but apparently, it doesn't and I wonder why. I am familiar with the things you said. Thank you anyway for trying to help.